# Не подключаются внешние стили

Tags: php, html, css, веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не подключаются внешние стили. В header.php у меня подключен style.css, в index.php который находится в той же папке что и хэдер стиль подгружается, а вот в index.php в другой папке стиль не подключается, хотя в нем я подключил файл header. Думаю дело в путях, но не уверен.

Вот header:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
<title>Магазин</title>
</head>
 
<div class = "header">
    <div class = "logo">ЗДЕСЬ БУДЕТ НАЗВАНИЕ</div>
</div>
```

Вот index.php в котором стиль не подключается

```
<?php

require_once ("../header.php");
require_once ("../menu.php");

?>



<?php

require_once ("../footer.php");

?>
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример кода, без примеров вашего кода никто не сможет (незахочет) вам помочь,

Comment: Скорее всего дело в пути и в этом легко удостоверится, если посмотреть на него из консоли браузера. Используйте путь не относительно файла, а относительно домена: `"/{путь до файла от корня}/style.css"`, в простейшем случае  `"/style.css"`.

Comment: У вас эти файлы (header.php , index.php) лежат в одной папке?
Судя по коду вы поднимаетесь на уровень выше и ищете эти файлы там.. попробуйте удалить (../) в путях

Comment: в index'е который лежит в одной папке с хэдером стиль подключается, а в другом index'е который лежит в другой папке, стиль не подключается

Comment: Скиньте структурное дерево вашего проекта (я имею ввиду древовидную структуру файлов ) скриншотом. Так будет проще вам помочь. Как и описали выше - дело наверняка в том, куда ссылаются ваши пути

Comment: Какая структура папок?

Comment: спасибо за ответы, проблема решилась

Comment: Не за что *(6 символов нужно)*

Comment: @DamirFelix По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0):

Я воспользовался советом

> Используйте путь не относительно файла, а относительно домена: `"/{путь до файла от корня}/style.css"`, в простейшем случае `"/style.css"`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
<title>Магазин</title>
</head>
 
<div class = "header">
    <div class = "logo">ЗДЕСЬ БУДЕТ НАЗВАНИЕ</div>
</div>
```